# How to display html text in Dev Nagari using Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

How to display html text in [Dev Nagari](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Devanagari) using Codeigniter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the same way you display text in any language. It's just characters. Make sure you consistently use the same character encoding everywhere (UTF-8 is the best choice).

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking to support multiple languages, take a look at the language library: http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/language.html